# Tomcat and LDAPS

Tags: tomcat, ldap

Can anyone tell me if Apache Tomcat will connect to a realm using LDAPS ?

Looking at:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/realm-howto.html

it doesn't mention anything about LDAPS.

Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [JDNDI Realm](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/realm-howto.html#JNDIRealm)

> JNDIRealm is an implementation of the
>   Tomcat Realm interface that looks up
>   users in an LDAP directory server
>   accessed by a JNDI provider
>   (typically, the standard LDAP provider
>   that is available with the JNDI API
>   classes). The realm supports a variety
>   of approaches to using a directory for
>   authentication.

http://dahbura.com/ldap/ldaprealm_howto.html

Answer (score 1):

JNDIRealm does exactly that, as stated in the other answer, or you can also use a JAASRealm and provide your own LoginModule that does your LDAP lookups for you.

Answer (score 0):

We have written own LDAP adapter to provide authentication over LDAP.

Comment: @AndyM - I can publish for you the piece of code. Would it be helpful?